# Sorting number in php query

Tags: php

I have a code here it works but i want to sort it out by min to max, what should i do?[image: this is my current output]

```
 <!-YEAR SELECTION->
                        <select name="year[]" id="year" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-default" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple>
                        <?php 
                          $sql_query =  "SELECT DISTINCT proj_year FROM lfpstatustable1";
                          $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
                          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                          echo "<option value='".$row[proj_year]."'>" . $row[proj_year] . "</option>";
                          }

                        ?>
                        </select>
```

Comment: order by `proj_year` ASC

Comment: Thank You! Very big help

Comment: That `SELECT` thingy is actually SQL, and given you use `mysqli_query`, it seems you're using MySQL, a database which is indeed commonly used together with PHP. SQL is a database-specific language and in that sense unrelated to PHP, so in the future you should include `SQL` or `MySQL` in your searches to find relevant tutorials, like [sorting with MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html), more easily.

Answer (score 0):

In your sql query add order by 
`SELECT DISTINCT proj_year FROM lfpstatustable1 order by proj_year asc`